# How to avoid duplicated random id selection in MySQL?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, random, duplicates

I need to select two unique random `id` from table `nodes` and insert it in `parent` column in `edges` table.
But problem is that they are sometimes duplicated and it need them to be always different, how could I avoid that, please?

the code:

```
const mysql = require('mysql');

const connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host: 'localhost',
  user: 'root',
  password: 'password',
  database: 'DAGtest3'
});

connection.connect((err) => {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log('Database Connected!');
});

var a = "INSERT INTO `edges` (`parent`, `child`) VALUES ((SELECT `id` FROM `nodes` ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 1 ) , (4) )";

connection.query(a, (err, res) => {
    if(err) throw err;
    console.log("1 edge inserted to previous data");
});
            
var b = "INSERT INTO `edges` (`parent`, `child`) VALUES ((SELECT `id` FROM `nodes` ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 1) , (4) )";
connection.query(b, (err, res) => {
    if(err) throw err;
    console.log("Another edge inserted to previous data");   
});
```

code for the tables:

```
CREATE TABLE nodes (
    id INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    sensorvalue VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    created_at TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
 
CREATE TABLE edges (
    parent INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES nodes(id) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE,
    child INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES nodes(id) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE,
    PRIMARY KEY (parent, child)
);
 
CREATE INDEX parent_idx ON edges (parent);
CREATE INDEX child_idx ON edges (child);
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hmm...I'm not a SQL expert, but if the subselect is randomly ordered, couldn't you just ask for `LIMIT 2` and fetch two random rows at once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want two sequential random selections, since there's a non-zero chance that the second random selection could return the same row as the first.  I think you should just fetch both rows at once:

```
INSERT INTO `edges` (`parent`, `child`) SELECT `id`, 4 FROM `nodes` ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 2;
```

So, your code would just have one query to execute, instead of two:

```
var a = "INSERT INTO `edges` (`parent`, `child`) SELECT `id`, 4 FROM `nodes` ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 2";

connection.query(a, (err, res) => {
    if(err) throw err;
    console.log("2 edges inserted to previous data");
});
```

When I set up your DB locally and run the above code, I get a successful insert:

```
Database Connected!
2 edges inserted to previous data
```

When I query the DB in the console I get:

```
mysql> select * from edges;
+--------+-------+
| parent | child |
+--------+-------+
|      2 |     4 |
|      3 |     4 |
+--------+-------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, but it shows this error `Subquery returns more than 1 row`

Comment: @ismsm The code above works.  Are you actually using the query I supplied, or are you still using the `VALUES (...)` syntax?